# Is there a NPM package to watch a MySql DB?

Tags: mysql, node.js

i just need to know if there is a nodejs package that watches a MySQL database and runs callbacks on events like updates on tables and columns.

Comment: I don’t think there is something as such, however there are other tools to monitor the activity like newrelic https://newrelic.com/ using this you can in fact monitor the queries and other things.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty The question is about watching database changes in a Node.js application.  Monitoring systems are unrelated.

Comment: @Brad I may have misquoted the question but this `that watches a MySQL database and runs callbacks on events like updates` definitely could be monitored via newrelic if we set that through the app. However structure changes on the DB will be very hard to detect. There are some mysql tools which does that but I have never used them.

Comment: The problem (at least my read of it) has nothing to do with monitoring though.  It has to do with doing something in the **application** when some data changes in a table.  The question is worded vaguely for sure... I'm inferring some things here by mention of "update", and that this question is posted in some form seemingly every other day on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

check out this npm package - I used it once and it works fine:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-events

Answer (score 0):

No such package will exist because what you want is already handled easily by whatever database package you're already using.  MySQL has no way of notifying clients when something changes.  Triggers only work inside the database, unless you extend MySQL itself.

All you can do is set up a polling query.

Comment: To whomever downvoted, if you have a better answer you should post it.